# Pass DIV offset during form submission JAVA / JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok I have a filter box where I do a submit on some form variable and also some hidden variables in Java.

For the purpose of this question im not gonna type out all the form variables.

What I need to do is pass the the DIV offset also to the form as variable's `top` and `left`

I know I can get the offset with javascript:

```
var offset = $("#filterPanel").offset(); 
        //alert( $("#filterPanel").offset() ); 
         var top = offset.top;
         var left = offset.left;
          alert( "top = " +  top); 
          alert( "left = " +  left)
```

what I need to do is pass those two variable also with my form when I press my "apply" button:

```
<div class="sideMenuPanel" style="display: none; width: 290px; top: ${panelTop}px;" id="filterPanel">
<form name="filterForm" action="process.mgmtview_update_filters" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="metricGroup" value="${filterForm.metricGroup}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="${referrer}" />



        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="filter_section_header" style="text-align: center;">
                <input style="font-size: 8pt;" name="actionButton" value="Apply" type="submit" />

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have hidden elements `top` and `left` in your form

`document.forms["filterForm"].top.value = top;`
`document.forms["filterForm"].left.value = left;`